# Laptop freezing randomly, but only in my office room

Tags: windows-7, laptop, freeze

I have Asus Laptop, running Windows 7 x64.
Laptop work just fine, no malware, no other problems,
except that battery is dead (battery still inside, laptop always plugged in AC).

Everywhere I go, to my clients, vacation, my living room ... laptop works normal,
absolutely never had any issues, except when I work from my office room (which is in my house).

When I work in my office, the laptop freezes (hangs) for a couple of seconds once in a while.
Freezing occurrence is random, sometimes freezes every couple of minutes, sometimes occurs every few hours, sometimes works just fine.

I have tried everything that crossed my mind. Temperature is OK, tried to adjust power management for some devices, tried to adjust various options for graphics acceleration switching, tried with LAN cable network with WIFI off, but nothing helps.

I need more hints, what to examine next, what can cause this freezes to happen?
Note again - living room NO PROBLEMS, Office room PROBLEMS - Same house, same network same everything except the room.

Comment: Peripherals are different, I guess?

Comment: Same peripherals (mouse, keyboard). In office, I plug in the external monitor via HDMI, but same happens with/without monitor.

Comment: Have you used something like Process Explorer to see what is using the resources? Check the Event Viewer to see if there are any errors or warnings? How about completely disconnect from the network in the office, both WiFi and LAN, then what happens? What other electronic devices are in the office where you have trouble?

Comment: 1. Remove battery completely and choose a power setting that doesn't involve battery usage i.e. always plugged in | 2. Clean up everything in the temp folders | 3. Degfrag your hard drive (if more than 20% is fragmented indicated by the defrag manager). |

Comment: With "same peripherals (mouse, keyboard)" do you mean "same mouse", "same keyboard", or do you mean "different mouse, different keyboard"?
In regards to your question: Mouse/keyboard software playing funny, and scheduled tasks are prime candidates for the issue you describe. Most other causes would cause the symptoms to show in the living room too.
One other possible cause is that the position of the laptop in the home office blocks the vents.

Answer (score 1):

Let's make a list of possible causes in case someone else stumbles upon this question:

- Scheduled tasks. The issue can depend on time instead of location. If the anti virus and the search indexer decide to have a little fight on a HDD, the computer will freeze occasionally.
- Peripherals losing connection. It might be that the computer isn't frozen at all, but the input commands (mouse, keyboard, etc) are jammed in some way, leading to the impression that the computer is frozen.
- Badly written drivers and bloated software bundles that come with your peripherals. *cough* SetPoint *cough*
- Air vents are blocked. The air flow to cool the internals of a computer may be blocked based on the position of the computer.
- Kids. (Or roommates). If someone streams a movie from your laptop to another device, your device may slow down. And some older WiFi cards can put a lot of stress on the processor.

Some of these can be excluded by running Task Manager in the background and looking at the graphs immediately after a freeze occurred.

Comment: Add another: poor wifi reception at that location.